# django auth manytomanyfield

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following models.py which is extending off of auth -

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class FileIndex(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    filetype = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    vendorid = models.IntegerField()
    vendorname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    tablename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'file_index'
        verbose_name = 'File/Vendor Index'
        verbose_name_plural = 'File/Vendor Indicies'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename

class UserFile(models.Model):
    userid_id = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    fileid_id = models.ManyToManyField(FileIndex)
    grant_date = models.DateTimeField()
    revoke_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_files'
        verbose_name = 'User File Matrix'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User File Matricies'
```

It then complains on my admin.py -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from api.models import *

# Register your models here.

class FileIndexAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('vendorname', 'filename')
    list_filter = ['vendorname', 'filename']
    search_fields = ['filename']

class UserFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('userid', 'fileid', 'grant_date', 'revoke_date')
    list_filter = ['userid']

admin.site.register(UserFile, UserFileAdmin)
admin.site.register(FileIndex, FileIndexAdmin)
```

It then crashes with the following message -

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: UserFileAdmin.list_display[0], 'userid_id' is not a callable or an attribute of 'UserFileAdmin' or found in the model 'UserFile'.
```

If I remove 'userid' and 'fileid' from the list_display it will load but then breaks when trying to select users/files to add/remove.

The SQL of these models is as follows -

```
CREATE TABLE auth_files
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  userid_id integer NOT NULL,
  fileid_id integer NOT NULL,
  grant_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  revoke_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT auth_files_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT auth_files_fileid_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fileid_id)
      REFERENCES file_index (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT auth_files_userid_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (userid_id)
      REFERENCES auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE auth_files
  OWNER TO rdsadmin;

CREATE TABLE file_index
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  filename character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  filetype character varying(16) NOT NULL,
  vendorid integer NOT NULL,
  vendorname character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  tablename character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT file_index_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE file_index
  OWNER TO rdsadmin;
```

Basically the auth_files/UserFile is associating the Auth/User table with the File info hence the manytomany both directions.

Am I doing something wrong in either my SQL or my models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically userid_id has a manytomanyfield to User, hence you will be creating another table named api_UserFile_userid_id and when you will display in admin list view you will have to pass the entire queryset of User model to select userids and hence you can query accordingly either on pk or username etc depending upon constraints

Hence define UserFile model class as:

```
class UserFile(models.Model):
    userid_id = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    fileid_id = models.ManyToManyField(FileIndex)
    grant_date = models.DateTimeField()
    revoke_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_files'
        verbose_name = 'User File Matrix'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User File Matricies'

    def get_userids(self):
        return "\n".join([u.pk for u in self.user.all()])

    def get_fileids(self):
        return "\n".join([f.pk for f in self.fileindex.all()])
```

In the admin.py change:

```
class UserFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('userid', 'fileid', 'grant_date', 'revoke_date')
    list_filter = ['userid']
```

To

```
class UserFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('get_userids', 'get_fileids', 'grant_date', 'revoke_date')
    list_filter = ['userid_id']
```

Comment: I think I understand where you're coming from however when I try to access the admin view I now get the following error `'UserFile' object has no attribute 'user'` on this line - `return "\n".join([u.pk for u in self.user.all()])`

Comment: IT was working fine on my system.So basically try using self.userid_id.all() instead of self.user.all() or provide some more information related to the error.

Comment: I'm going to start a new project using the models.py and admin.py changes above and try again.  Even with self.userid_id.all() it complains with the following - `"auth_files_userid_id" is an index` I just realized now it might be because I'm using Mezzanine and it's in turn using Grapelli.

Comment: marked as answered.  Although I was looking at this wrong as M2M I did use the two def's you provided.